# Foreign value relations to store in revisionable

Tags: php, laravel, revisionable

I am using `VentureCraft/revisionable` in my Laravel project. I wanted to work on multiple models at once, but since revisionable doesn't allow me to do so, I did that in single models.

There was this one instance, where I got this revisionable output as this

```
Chris changed status from 4 to 5.
```

But, instead this, I wanted something like this:

```
Chris changed status from New to In progress.
```

4 and 5 were the foreign keys to the name New and In progress.

How can I use foreign value relations in revisionable.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this package, but looking at the documentation it looks like you need to implement the `identifiableName()` method in the related model. Instead of displaying the foreign keys, it will display whatever is returned from the `identifiableName()` method.

So, if your related model is `Status`, you would do something like:

```
class Status extends Eloquent {
    use Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

    public function identifiableName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple foreign keys?

Comment: @phantomphoenix You would need to provide some code and more explanation of what you're trying to do. My understanding is that you have something like a `Task` model that `belongsTo` `Status` (task has the `status_id`). When the `status_id` on the task changes, the revision history will look up the status record, and print the value from the `identifiableName()` method. So, I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. I have tried various things to get indentifiableName() working but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Do what @patricus said but instead of

```
    return $this->name;
```

point to the value you want revisionable to display

```
    return $this->[whatever field you have in the db];
```